# Не могу правильно настроить цикл и создать легенду

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in np.arange(11, 15):
    fname = f'C:/Users/79529/Desktop/Nastya/KE-{i}.uxd'
    x = np.loadtxt(fname, usecols = 0)
    y = np.loadtxt(fname, usecols = 1)
    for k in np.arange(0, 6000, 1500):
        plt.plot(x, y + k)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Добрый день!
В этом цикле я создаю 4 графика и хочу, чтобы они не накладывались друг на друга.
Для этого я хотел, чтоб каждый последовательный график располагался выше предыдущего.
Но у меня получается так, что графики накладываются друг на друга, как мне правильно
сделать цикл?
Еще вопрос: Как мне указать легенду. Допустим: 1 график назвать хочу альфа железо, второй гамма железо и т.д.

Comment: А что вы хотите увидеть в легенде, собственно?

Comment: Правильнее будет наверное спросить, как мне указать легенду. Допустим: 1 график назвать хочу альфа железо, второй гамма железо и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял код на вообще другой, сразу не заметил, что у вас ещё один цикл и вообще другая логика отрисовки, чем я думал:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = ['альфа железо', 'бетта железо', 'гамма железо', 'дельта железо']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(16, 4), sharey=True)
for ai, i in enumerate(np.arange(11, 15)):
    fname = f'C:/Users/79529/Desktop/Nastya/KE-{i}.uxd'
    x = np.loadtxt(fname, usecols = 0)
    y = np.loadtxt(fname, usecols = 1)
    ax[ai].set_title(names[ai])
    for k in np.arange(0, 6000, 1500):
        ax[ai].plot(x, y + k)
plt.show()
```

Данные у меня, конечно, искусственные, ваших данных у меня нет. Но примерно получается такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А, вы вроде вертикально хотели, тогда поменять одну строчку:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(4, 16), sharex=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы вы весь код добавить, я просто не совсем понимаю, как это все выглядит.

Comment: Премного благодарен.